# How do I convert JPG to IPIX?

Tags: 360-panorama

Are there apps for converting jpeg photos taken by a 360 camera, such as a Ricoh Theta, to IPIX format? I have found apps for converting from IPIX to regular jpeg, but there does not seem to be an app for converting 360º photos in jpg. Please advise.

Comment: IPIX is long dead. Is there a reason you need to create .ipx format?

Answer (score 5):

The main reason you aren't finding applications to translate into IPIX format is because a) it's a dead format, and b) proprietary viewers have been superseded by HTML5. It's a PITA to have to force everyone you want to see your panorama to have to download, install, and use a piece of proprietary software to do so.

HTML5 has mostly supplanted the older proprietary (and currently unsupported) VR formats, like QTVR and IPIX.

I would recommend looking at [Pano2VR](http://ggnome.com/pano2vr) from Gardon Gnome or [krpano](http://krpano.com/tools/). You can feed these tools an equirectangular JPEG and they can output the HTML5 files needed for you to publish your panorama as an interactive VR panorama or virtual tour.